# On the equality of two sets (a doubt from Probability with Martingales).

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu) $ be $([0,1], \mathcal{B}[0,1], Leb)$. Let $\epsilon(k)$ be a sequence of strictly positive numbers s.t. $\epsilon(k) \downarrow 0$.

Let $V = Q \cap [0,1],$ the set of rationals in $[0,1]$. Since $V$ is a countable union of singletons it has Lebesgue measure $0$. We can include $V$ in an open subset of $S$ of measure at most $4 \epsilon(k)$ as follows:

$$V \subset G_k = \bigcup_{n \in N} [(v_n - \epsilon(k)2^{-n}, v_n + \epsilon(k)2^{-n}) \cap S] =: \bigcup_n I_{n,k} $$

The text then states that $\bigcap_k G_k \ne V$. I am having troubles seeing why this is true.

My (wrong) reasoning is as follows: I am taking the countable intersection of sets of the form $[(v_n - \epsilon(k)2^{-n}, v_n + \epsilon(k)2^{-n}) \cap S]$ for every $k$, I notice that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (v_n - \epsilon(k)2^{-n}) = v_n$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (v_n - \epsilon(k)2^{-n}) = v_n$ but $v_n$ is present in every set so the intersection is just the single point $v_n$ and the same for all other sets. This would imply that $\bigcap_k G_k $ is included in $V$ but then $\bigcap_k G_k = V$.

SO why is $\bigcap_k G_k \ne V$? or in other words why is $\bigcap_k G_k $ not included in $V$.

Comment: For each $k$, $G_k$ is a dense open subset of $S$. Thus the complement of $\bigcap_k G_k$ is meagre. $\mathbb{Q}\cap S$ is meagre, so $(\mathbb{Q}\cap S) \cup (S\setminus \bigcap_k G_k)$ is meagre. But $[0,1]$ is compact, so it's not meagre (in itself). It follows that $\mathbb{Q}\cap S \subsetneq \bigcap_k G_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I am going to have to look up the definiton of a meagre :).

Comment: meagre = of the first category = countable union of nowhere dense sets

Comment: @DanielFischer Does this argument also imply that $\bigcap_k G_k $ is not included in $V$? because this is what I was trying to ask. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, $\bigcap_k G_k$ is much larger than $V$. Topologically, "almost all" points of $[0,1]$ lie in the intersection. [While measure-theoretically, almost all points lie in the complement of the intersection, which is a null set (wrt Lebesgue measure).]

Comment: @DanielFischer I still seems to me that $\bigcap_k  \bigcup_{n \in N} [(v_n - \epsilon(k)2^{-n}, v_n + \epsilon(k)2^{-n}) \cap S] = Q \cap [0,1]  $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove that the intersection contains irrational numbers:

By construction, each $G_k$ is an open subset of $S$, and $V \subset G_k$, hence $G_k$ is a dense open subset of $S$. Then $U_k := G_k \setminus \{v_k\}$ is also a dense open subset of $S$. By Baire's theorem,

$$\bigcap_{k = 0}^\infty U_k \neq \varnothing,$$

and

$$\bigcap_{k = 0}^\infty U_k = \bigcap_{k = 0}^\infty (G_k \setminus \{v_k\}) = \Biggl(\bigcap_{k = 0}^\infty G_k\Biggr) \setminus \Biggl(\bigcup_{k = 0}^\infty \{v_k\}\Biggr) = \Biggl(\bigcap_{k = 0}^\infty G_k\Biggr) \setminus V$$

then shows $\bigcap_k G_k \not\subset V$. In fact, $S \setminus \bigcap_k U_k = \bigcup_k (S\setminus U_k)$ is a union of countably many nowhere dense subsets of $S$, and such sets are called meagre (or "of the first category"). Meagre sets are in a topological sense small (when the ambient space is not itself meagre), so topologically, most points of $S$ lie in $\bigcap_k U_k$ - although that is a set of measure $0$, so measure-theoretically, most points of $S$ lie outside of $S$; despite the close connection of the Lebesgue measure and the topology of $S$, the two concepts have very different ideas about "largeness" of sets.

For completeness, we can include a proof of Baire's theorem, where we have the free choice whether we use the version for complete metric spaces or the version for locally compact spaces. Let's use the version for locally compact spaces.

Since $U_0$ is dense and $S\neq \varnothing$,, we have $U_0 \neq \varnothing$. Pick an $x_0 \in U_0$. Since $S$ is locally compact, and $U_0$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$, there is a compact neighbourhood $K_0$ of $x_0$ contained in $U_0$.

Once we have picked points $x_0,x_1,\dotsc, x_{k-1}$ and compact neighbourhoods $K_j$ of $x_j$ satisfying $K_j \subset K_{j-1}$ for $0 < j < k$, we can continue the construction by noting that $U_k$ is a dense open set, and $K_{k-1}$ has nonempty interior (since it is a neighbourhood of $x_{k-1}$), hence $W_k := U_k \cap \overset{\Large\circ}{K}_{k-1} \neq \varnothing$. Now we pick an $x_k \in W_k$, and by local compacteness of $S$, a compact neighbourhood $K_k$ of $x_k$ such that $K_k \subset W_k$.

In that way we obtain a nested sequence $K_0 \supset K_1 \supset K_2 \supset \dotsc$ of nonempty compact sets, and by compactness,

$$\bigcap_{k = 0}^\infty K_k \neq \varnothing.$$

But by construction $K_k \subset U_k$ for all $k$.

---

So why does your reasoning suggest that $\bigcap_k G_k = V$?

You look at one interval $I_{n,k}$ instead of the whole set $G_k$.

Indeed, as $k \to \infty$, for each fixed $n$, the intervals

$$I_{n,k} = (v_n - \epsilon(k)2^{-n}, v_n + \epsilon(k)2^{-n}) \cap S$$

shrink to $\{v_n\}$ as $k \to \infty$. But if we write $\bigcap_k G_k$ as a union of intersections, we get

$$\bigcap_k \Biggl(\bigcup_n I_{n,k}\Biggr) = \bigcup_{f\colon \mathbb{N}\to{\mathbb{N}}} \Biggl( \bigcap_k I_{f(k),k}\Biggr),$$

a union of uncountably many ($2^{\aleph_0}$) intersections of countably many intervals. It is trivial that

$$\bigcap_k I_{f(k),k}$$

is nonempty for every constant $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ - those give the $\{v_n\}$ - but we also have

$$\bigcap_k I_{f(k),k} \neq \varnothing$$

for many non-constant functions $f$ - it is harder to find functions $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that are not eventually constant for which the intersection is nonempty, but Baire's theorem shows that there are uncountably many such functions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! This tells me a lot, but gives me other questions too.  It is the first time I see $\bigcap_k \Biggl(\bigcup_n I_{n,k}\Biggr) = \bigcup_{f\colon \mathbb{N}\to{\mathbb{N}}} \Biggl( \bigcap_k I_{f(k),k}\Biggr),$, I am making $n$ a function of $k$?

Comment: That's the end result. I suggest starting with (small) finite index sets and do everything by hand to get a grip on it, but the end result is that if $x \in \bigcap_k \bigcup_n I_{n,k}$, then for every $k$, there is at least one $n(k)$ such that $x\in I_{n(k),k}$, so there is a function from the set of all $k$ (which is $\mathbb{N}$ here) to the set of all $n$ (also $\mathbb{N}$ here), such that $x \in \bigcap_k I_{n(k),k}$. Conversely, since $I_{n(k),k} \subset \bigcup_n I_{n,k}$, the union on the right is a subset of the intersection on the left.

Comment: Wouldn't one non-constant function $f$ that works be $f$ defined as mapping the even natural numbers to $1$ and the odd to $2$? But this would still give us a $\{v_n \}$.

Comment: That wouldn't work, for all large enough $k$, we have $I_{1,k} \cap I_{2,k} = \varnothing$, and by the nestedness, $I_{1,m} \cap I_{2,\ell} = \varnothing$ for all $m,\ell \geqslant k$. To get something with a nonempty intersection $\bigcap_k I_{f(k),k}$, you need an $f$ that either is constant from some point on (and before that doesn't pick an interval far away), or it must be unbounded. At most one $n$ can appear infinitely often as a value - then the intersection will be $\{v_n\}$ if it's not empty, so such a function doesn't give anything you couldn't get with constant functions.

Comment: Functions that give irrationals in the intersection must "converge to $+\infty$". That is of course not sufficient, plenty of such functions will give you an empty intersection.